# Customer sensitive data encryption in GCP ( GCS, BQ...)

Tags: encryption, google-cloud-platform

We know that there are three options
1.(default) Google-managed encryption keys
2. Customer-supplied encryption keys
3. Customer-managed encryption keys

For a particular  customer data, how we can restrict the access so that the data remains unreadable even if it is downloadable.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot download encrypted data from GCP/BQ/etc without the encryption key or access to the encryption key.

The exception is if you upload self-encrypted data as normal data.